# Query string for nested multiselect

Tags: rest, request, swagger, restful-url

I have a situation where I have nested multi-select.

```
   1.Football
   1.1 Messi
   1.2 Ronaldo
   1.3 Neymar
   2. Tenis
   2.1  Novak Djokovic
   2.2  Fedrer
   2.3  Messi
```

and I want to create an endpoint for this query which can fetch multiplayer. If it would be just one single select in-game and single select in the player then I could do

1. ?game=tennis&player=Messi
2. ?game=Football&player=Messi

   But I need a single endpoint which can fetch multiplayer in multiple games. Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I properly understand what your issue is, but you could do:

```
?game=tennis,football&player=messi,fedrer
```

```
?game=tennis&game=football&player=messi&player=fedrer
```

But you must be aware that, the [query string](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4), by definition, is *non-hierarchical*:

> [**3.4.  Query**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4)
>
> The query component contains non-hierarchical data that, along with
> data in the path component, serves to identify a
> resource within the scope of the URI's scheme and naming authority
> (if any).  The query component is indicated by the first question
> mark (`?`) character and terminated by a number sign (`#`) character
> or by the end of the URI. [...]